# Easing animation in JavaScript without jQuery or other libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to have a `<div>` come into a webpage from the right when you hover over it. So something like this:

```
$('div.from_right').hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({right: '-300px'});
});
```

But I don't want to use jQuery or any other libraries. Is there a built-in mechanism within JavaScript to animate the position? Or do I call `requestAnimationFrame()` repeatedly until the `<div>` is where I want it to be?

I only care about modern browsers.

Comment: If you only care about modern browsers anyway, why not rely on CSS transitions? You can make do without JS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use CSS transition.

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transition:margin 3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:margin 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:margin 2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:margin 2s ease-out;
    transition:margin 2s ease-out;
}
div:hover {
    margin-left:300px;
}
```

[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/LnW4J/)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't even think of this!